# After migrating to MongoDB Atlas, no previous users can authenticate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongorestore

I assume I am doing something wrong, but the documentation has not pointed me in the right direction yet.

I am migrating a self-hosted MongoDB instance database to the MongoDB Atlas platform. I have successfully uploaded a dump using `mongorestore`, but now none of my `users` objects can authenticate. I want to say I read somewhere in the docs that you can't migrate pre-existing users or something?

This is the command I am using to restore from a dump

```
mongorestore --host <MY_CLUSTER>:27017 --nsExclude 'admin.system.*' --ssl --username <USER> --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --db=<DB_NAME> .backups/12-23-2019/backup/
```

Comment: and if you create a new user?? ...still the problem ?

Comment: I can't create a new user without being able to log into the app ‍♂️

Comment: `I can't create a new user without being able to log into the app ` - What do you mean by this ? an app user (stored app users details in collection)? this is a bit confusing but what I understood is you're not able to access DB using your existing DB user credentials, if that's correct I think you can't cause these both are two different instances, collection data can be migrated I doubt whether all system data including user details gets migrated to mongoAtlas, Anyhow you can login to https://cloud.mongodb.com/user#/atlas/login where your cluster is hosted & create DB users !!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restore users to atlas structure as mentioned before

you have to configure a mongocli environment to mass create users in your Atlas cluster, unless you want to use the "Database Access" panel and create one by one (painful).

Not gonna go into details about how to configure mongocli, but once you've done with it, I made a simple script that retrieve all the users from you original server and script into the create users into mongocli, it uses mongo shell and jq.

```
mongo mongodb://youroriginalcluster --quiet --eval 'db.system.users.find({}, {"user" : 1, "db" : 1, "roles" : 1}).toArray();'  | jq -r  '.[] | " mongocli atlas dbuser create --username \(.user) --password PASSWORD --role \(.roles[].role)@\(.db)"'
```

Still needs some minor adjustments and it does not retrieve the password, but it should save you some time

Answer (score 0):

`mongorestore` has a specific option for restoring users and roles: `--restoreDbUsersAndRoles` (note that it works only if you backed an entire instance or used the `--dumpDbUsersAndRoles` option with `mongodump` for a single `--db`).

Regardless of this, Atlas does not support migrating users from the source database since it manages users from the Atlas console rather than in the database itself. Users can be created in Atlas using the `Database Access` menu option.

From the [Atlas Manual](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongorestore/#cluster-security):

> Atlas fully manages MongoDB database user creation. If the source cluster enforces authentication, use the mongorestore --nsExclude to exclude the admin.system.* namespace. You cannot migrate any existing user or role information to Atlas.